# VB.Net Box Plot Creation

Tags: vb.net, boxplot

I am struggling understanding how *boxplots* work *VB.Net*. The following works but it plots the *boxplot* along with a bar chart. I just want the box plot. I have figured out you can disable offending series to remove them from the chart but this seems like the wrong approach...

Current Plot

[image: Current Plot]

What is wrong with my code? Again, all I want is the boxplot.

```
    Dim yVal As Double() = {55.62, 45.54, 73.45, 9.73, 88.42, 45.9, 63.6, 85.1, 67.2, 23.6}
    Dim yVal2 As Double() = {35.62, 25.54, 43.45, 23.73, 43.42, 12.9, 23.6, 65.1, 54.2, 41.6}

    Chart1.Series.Clear()
    Chart1.Series.Add("BoxPlotSeries")

    Chart1.Series.Add("1")
    Chart1.Series("1").Points.DataBindY(yVal)

    Chart1.Series.Add("2")
    Chart1.Series("2").Points.DataBindY(yVal2)

    Chart1.Series("BoxPlotSeries").ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot
    Chart1.Series("BoxPlotSeries")("BoxPlotSeries") = "1;2"

    Chart1.Series("BoxPlotSeries")("BoxPlotWhiskerPercentile") = "15"
    Chart1.Series("BoxPlotSeries")("BoxPlotShowAverage") = "true"
    Chart1.Series("BoxPlotSeries")("BoxPlotShowMedian") = "true"
    Chart1.Series("BoxPlotSeries")("BoxPlotShowUnusualValues") = "true"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable those series

```
Chart1.Series("1").Enabled = False
Chart1.Series("2").Enabled = False
```

[image]

Maybe you don't like how the [custom properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456700.aspx) of the series work. I don't either! But it seems there's no way around indexing them by string name (and setting the values as strings, even if they are boolean or numeric, as you saw). Here is a [complete list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456764.aspx) of these properties.

I would have object references to the series outside of the scope where they are created. You can then manipulate them later as needed (i.e. adding / changing data) without indexing the chart's Series collection with the string name. This might be of some relief

```
Private boxPlotSeries As Series
Private series1 As Series
Private series2 As Series

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim yVal As Double() = {55.62, 45.54, 73.45, 9.73, 88.42, 45.9, 63.6, 85.1, 67.2, 23.6}
    Dim yVal2 As Double() = {35.62, 25.54, 43.45, 23.73, 43.42, 12.9, 23.6, 65.1, 54.2, 41.6}

    Chart1.Series.Clear()

    boxPlotSeries = New Series() With {
        .Name = "BoxPlotSeries",
        .ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot}

    boxPlotSeries("BoxPlotSeries") = "1;2"
    boxPlotSeries("BoxPlotWhiskerPercentile") = "15"
    boxPlotSeries("BoxPlotShowAverage") = "True"
    boxPlotSeries("BoxPlotShowMedian") = "True"
    boxPlotSeries("BoxPlotShowUnusualValues") = "True"

    series1 = New Series() With {
        .Name = "1",
        .Enabled = False}
    series1.Points.DataBindY(yVal)

    series2 = New Series() With {
        .Name = "2",
        .Enabled = False}
    series2.Points.DataBindY(yVal2)

    Chart1.Series.Add(boxPlotSeries)
    Chart1.Series.Add(series1)
    Chart1.Series.Add(series2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw this earlier but it seems like the wrong approach. Am I creating the series correctly in the first place?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way you do it. I personally prefer creating the series off the chart and then adding them. This way you could keep an object reference to the series instead of having to index the Chart.Series collection by string name. I'll paste my series initialization code in my answer.